# Referencing one number to another number

Tags: bash

I have a question which I think is fairly simply but I am new to Bash and can't find much info on this.

5 references 3
10 references 4
20 references 10
30 references 20

```
inputBeforeLookup = 5 #this the number which needs to look up 3 above^^^^
# 10 would lookup and return 4
#20 returns 10

start = 1
end = $start + $lookupNumberfromFile # 3 in this case, since input was 5

seq $start $end


1
2
3
4
```

I guess my question here is what is the proper way to create like a configuration file which references numbers to other numbers?

If there is a better way than the snippet of code I posted I am always open to suggestions, like i said I am learning.

I am new to this so I am not sure if the syntax is 100% correct. I am more so looking for a solution on the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: You could use an array. However your question contains too many extraneous details, and the actual purpose is unclear.

Comment: For 5 your expect 3, what do you expect for 30? Is it 20 or is it 4 ( 30 -> 20 -> 10 -> 4)

Comment: It is unclear what the input is and what the expected output is.

Comment: ok so i have an input number, and that input number references another number in a config file(is this the best solution?). So if i have an input of 5, i need to use the number 3. (If i have an input of 10, i need to use  4), (if i have 20 i need to use 10)

Comment: What you are searching for is an associative array. A nicely explained example you can find [here](https://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2012/10/17/bash-associative-array-examples/).

Comment: Yup, looks like this is it.  MYMAP=( [5]=3 [10]=4 [20]=10), then MYMAP(5) would return 3.  disregard syntax, I will work on it tonight

Answer (score 1):

Hope this sample helps you regarding variable expansion in bash:

Notice that: the `\` prevents the expansion of $$ (current process id). For triple substitution you need double `eval` and so on....

```
#!/bin/bash

one=1
two=one
three=two
four=three
five=four

echo $one
eval echo \$$two
eval eval echo \\$\$$three
eval eval eval echo \\\\$\\$\$$four
eval eval eval eval echo \\\\\\\\$\\\\$\\$\$$five
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

Bonus: 
In `zsh` you can use nested substitution much more easily:

```
#!/bin/zsh

one=1
two=one
three=two
four=three
five=four

echo $one
echo ${(P)two}
echo ${(P)${(P)three}}
...
```

http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html

Comment: I dont think that i want to make a whole bunch of variables in my bash script, unless i have to, i would rather create another data file with them in it. thanks tho.

Answer (score 0):

Set up an associative array, then test it with numbers *1* to *30*.  Those numbers that don't reference other numbers are printed *as is*:

```
MYMAP=( [5]=3 [10]=4 [20]=10 [30]=20 )
seq 30 | while read x ; do echo ${MYMAP[$x]:-$x} ; done | paste - - - - -
```

That last `| paste - - - - -` isn't necessary, but 5 column output is easier to follow given that the input has several multiples of 5.  Output:

```
1   2   3   4   3
6   7   8   9   4
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  10
21  22  23  24  25
26  27  28  29  20
```