# How to include parameter inside another parameter in bash

Tags: bash, shell

doing the following:

```
for i in {0..3};do
        echo "${Card_${i}}"
done
```

my point is to get the print of parameters named "Card_1" "Card_2" and Card_3

Comment: for example if Card_1=222 the function will print 222

Comment: Use arrays. `Card=(1 2 3); for i in {0...3}; do echo ${Card[$i]}; done`. If not, you need to use eval. `eval echo "\"\${Card_$i}\""`. Eval is bad.

Comment: each card is an array anyway so i'm not sure it will work

Comment: Take a look to this old answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51083594/referencing-one-number-to-another-number/51083907#51083907

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly possible to dynamically create variable names using an expansion:

```
$ card_1=111
$ card_2=222
$ card_3=333
$ printf '%s\n' $card_{1..3}
111
222
333
```

Brace expansion happens before parameter expansion, so `$card_{1..3}` is expanded to `$card_1 $card_2 $card_3` before the parameters are expanded.

That said, it looks like you're using numerical suffixes to emulate an array:

```
$ cards=( 111 222 333 444 )
$ printf '%s\n' "${cards[@]:0:3}"
111
222
333
```

I used a slice `0:3` just to show how they work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use variable indirection. However, since you've [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379328/how-to-include-parameter-inside-another-parameter-in-bash/51380563#comment89730452_51379328) that each `card` is an array itself, `declare -n` (requires `bash` 4.3 or newer) might be your best option:

```
card_1=(c1a c1b)
card_2=(c2a c2b)

for i in {1..2}; do
    declare -n arr=card_$i
    echo "${arr[0]}"
done

# output:
# c1a
# c2a
```